# Database Design when Admin and Employee have similar roles except Admin can see all the other Employees Data

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

We are building a system with concept of Admin and Employee. so basically Admin is an employee with all powers and can view all the data created by other Employee.

```
CREATE TABLE `Vendor` (
  `vendor_Id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `email_Id` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `landline_Number` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mobile_Number` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address_Line1` varchar(65) NOT NULL,
  `address_Line2` varchar(65) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `pincode` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`vendor_Id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `Employee` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `vendor_Id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `role` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `employee_username_unique` (`username`),
  KEY `employee_vendor_id_foreign` (`vendor_Id`),
  CONSTRAINT `employee_vendor_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`vendor_Id`) REFERENCES `Vendor` (`vendor_Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=12 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


CREATE TABLE `Action` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `emp_Id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `assigned_To` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `deadline` datetime(3) NOT NULL,
  `notes` varchar(400) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `action_emp_id_foreign` (`emp_Id`),
  CONSTRAINT `action_emp_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`emp_Id`) REFERENCES `Employee` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=12 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

There are other tables Roles and EmployeeRoles which I thought were not required here.

**Approach 1** : Now, when the Admin logs in to see all the Actions created by everyone

1. we first need to query the Employee table to find all the employees of that Vendor (we will have the Vendor_Id stored in the session when the admin/employee logs in)
2. Then query the Action table with where in employee_Id array from Step 1

Is this a good approach ?

**Approach 2** : or in Action table, I shall store Vendor_Id for each record (mainly all this effort only so that when Admin logs in I can easily retrieve all the records for that Vendor. When Admin logs in from the session I can easily find the Vendor_Id and query the Action table.

I don't know at this moment which would be a better approach. Any suggestions ? 
Like Action, there are other 3 tables where similar concept needs to be applied.

Edit 1: There can be a case where we can have  multiple vendors registered under a Single brand (future extension) and the Super-Admin would like to analyze the data across multiple branches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First approach is the basic normalisation approach. As you are putting `vendor_id` into session, you can also put employee array (having `emp_ids` belonging to that vendor) into session or cache. Here you would not have to query again and again as it will be refreshed when session or cache expires.

Second solution is the denormalised one. Here you would run into problems based on consistency. On updation of each vendor_id-emp_id mapping you need to update your action table too.

So you have to compare the volume of write queries to read queries. If read queries are too high then go with second. But I suppose there will be only 1-2 admins in an organisation of small size. I would go with Ist until I run into some serious performance issues.

Comment: Thank you. I thought of similar thing to cache or store employee details in session. So we use pagination for Actions - don’t you feel this will be an expensive query ?  For second solution - I can’t think of scenarios where the mapping will change. We can use a active flag to max disable the employee.  Do you think second solution will ease out the query part because of Vendor_Ids presence though it may also lead to more bytes

Comment: can you check Edit in the question. What when we have multiple vendors registered under a big Org then running similar query will become like : when the super admin logs in - find all the vendors related to it - find all the employees for each Vendor and like built an array - > now when you want to query you can use wherein clause (but the employee id list will be too big)

Comment: If you have used proper indexes. query structure and pagination, I don't thing it would take *that* much of a time. Anyway, in future if you have multiple admins and these kind of read queries increase, you can denormalise the `Action` table having both `vendor_id`, `org_id` into it. But take care of consistency and other issues I mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

You can stick to solution 1. With an index on the Vendor id in the employee table you should be good with an inner join with actions table.(Unless you are planning to have millions of rows in the tables and looking towards having of performance at single digit milliseconds level)

Comment: I would update this to be more explicit about what alternative there is and how the performance is gained.